# How to avoid many re-renders in recursive methods with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Have this component https://codesandbox.io/s/l2nq31r1mz and it's re-renders completely when i click on list element. How to avoid many re-renders? You can see re-renders count in console

Comment: In addition to the link, all relevant code that is necessary to understand the question should be presented in the question. Links tend to break.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your `console.log(render${this.renderTimes++});` call in the `render()` function, you will see that the component only renders once and on every nav item click it will re-render only one time. Although `generateMenu()` gets called multiple times, React optimizes that and triggers only one component re-render.

Answer (score 0):

setState will trigger a re-render and it re-renders the links for each time you call **generateMenu** and you also call **generateMenu** inside of its self. From your link every time you click it, it runs **generateMenu** 6 times.

To stop it completely re-rendering maybe you could make **generateMenu** a new component